# String to Date conversion - Java

Tags: java, string, date

I am having this problem with the conversion of string to date, I want to insert into the database date of format "dd.MM.yy" using this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
String d = f.format(new Date());
System.out.println("String: " + d);
Date d1 = f.parse(d);
System.out.println("Date: " +d1);
```

Output:

```
String: 16.06.17
Date: Fri Jun 16 00:00:00 EEST 2017
```

I tried other methods but the date is always printing in this format "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy".

Comment: A date has no custom format. So re-think what you're actually trying to do. It makes also no sense to store a date in a specific format in the database. Use the proper column type instead.

Comment: You are missing the point: the Date type variable d1 has the correct **value**, it's just that its default toString as used in the println statement uses some other format. Unless you will be inserting the date value as a string in the database (which would be a very bad idea anyways) everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. `Date` class overrides the `.toString()` method so when you do `System.out.println("Date: " +d1)` you're actually doing `System.out.println("Date: " + d1.toString());`

If you want to print your date with the format you provide you'll need to use `format()` from your `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
String d = f.format(new Date());
System.out.println("String: " + d);
Date d1 = f.parse(d);
System.out.println("Date: " + f.format(d1));
```

Answer (score 0):

**dd.MM.YY** is not a valid sql type date. So you can not use this format directly to your database. If it is required you can use an alternative by making database field as varchar so it can accept your formatted date.And when you want to use this date you can simply format back this.

```
    // For example retrieved from database.
    String date = "2012/12/12";

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");

    Date newDate = f.format(new Date(date)); // Will hold date 12.12.12
```

Comment: To store a date in your database you should prefer a `date` datatype over `varchar`. That’s what it is made for.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but you are doing a number of things wrong.

While displaying two-digit years to the user is OK in situations where the century in unambiguous, you should never store two-digit years to your database. You are creating another [Y2K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem). If you want to store years as string, store four digits.

But don’t store strings. Your RDBMS no doubt has a `date` datatype exactly made for and suited for storing dates. Use it instead.

In Java don’t use the long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Their replacements came out in 2014. So use `LocalDate` for dates. Get a new JDBC driver (it should be JDBC 4.2 compliant) and store your `LocalDate` directly into the `date` typed column of your database. No need for any formatting.

In case you need to display your date to the user in `dd.MM.yy` format, use `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 16);
System.out.println("The date is "
        + myDate.format(DateTimeFormat.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy")));
```

(I have not tested; if there’s a typo you cannot fix yourself, please revert.)

PS

> the date is always printing in this format "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy".

Yes, `java.util.Date` prints that way. Always. A `Date` object does not hold a format in it (the same holds true for `LocalDate`). This has been explained in many places. See for example [All about `java.util.Date`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), scroll down to the section *How do I convert a `Date` to a different format?*